# Генерация классов Entity Framework из XSD-схемы

Tags: entity-framework, xsd, codefirst

Есть xsd-схема, описывающая dataset.

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность сгенерировать на ее основе классы Entity Framework.

Иначе говоря, возможно ли преобразование XSD в Code First Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сначала сгенерировать классы из XSD схемы, используя on-line конверторы и полученные классы использовать в EF.

Comment: Если пишешь ответ, то опиши его (ответ) более раскрыто.